# Run NUnit tests in .NET Core

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing, nunit, asp.net-core-1.0

I am trying to run unit tests for my C# project with .NET Core.
I am using a [Docker](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Docker_%28software%29) container for the runtime.

Dockerfile

```
FROM microsoft/dotnet:0.0.1-alpha
RUN mkdir /src
WORKDIR /src
ADD . /src
RUN dotnet restore
```

"NUnit" and "NUnit.Runners" have been added into project.json

```
"version": "1.0.0-*",
"compilationOptions": {
    "emitEntryPoint": true
},

"dependencies": {
    "NETStandard.Library": "1.0.0-rc2-23811",
    "NUnit": "3.2.0",
    "NUnit.Runners": "3.2.0"
},
"frameworks": {
    "dnxcore50": { }
}
```

Run `dotnet restore` successfully with the following output

```
...
log  : Installing NUnit.ConsoleRunner 3.2.0.
log  : Installing NUnit.Extension.NUnitV2ResultWriter 3.2.0.
log  : Installing NUnit.Extension.NUnitV2Driver 3.2.0.
log  : Installing NUnit.Extension.VSProjectLoader 3.2.0.
log  : Installing NUnit.Extension.NUnitProjectLoader 3.2.0.
log  : Installing NUnit.Runners 3.2.0.
info : Committing restore...
log  : Restore completed in 4352ms.
```

I tried to run the tests with:

`dotnet nunit`

`dotnet nunit-console`

But it doesn't work.

How am I going to call the runner? Or is there another unit testing framework that works with the current version of .NET Core?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

**Update 4:** The [NUnit3TestAdapter v3.8](https://www.nuget.org/packages/NUnit3TestAdapter/3.8.0) has been released, so it is no longer alpha.

**Update 3:** 
With [NUnit3TestAdapter v3.8.0-alpha1](https://www.nuget.org/packages/NUnit3TestAdapter/3.8.0-alpha1) it is possible now to run the tests using `dotnet test` command. You just need to have these dependencies in your test project:

```
<PackageReference Include="nunit" Version="3.7.0" />
<PackageReference Include="NUnit3TestAdapter" Version="3.8.0-*" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.NET.Test.Sdk" Version="15.*" />
```

You can try it out!

**Update 2:** Visual Studio 2017 and the move from `project.json` to `csproj` made the `dotnet-test-nunit` test adapter obsolete, so we needed to release another updated adapter to run .NET Core tests. Please see [Testing .NET Core with NUnit in Visual Studio 2017](http://www.alteridem.net/2017/05/04/test-net-core-nunit-vs2017/) if you are using VS2017 and the new .NET Core tooling. See the update below if you are using `project.json`.

**Update:** NUnit now has support for `dotnet test`, so you no longer have to use NUnitLite. See [testing .NET Core RC2 and ASP.NET Core RC2 using NUnit 3](http://www.alteridem.net/2016/06/18/nunit-3-testing-net-core-rc2/).

---

NUnit console (and the underlying NUnit Engine) do not support running unit tests against .NET core yet. Hopefully we will get that support in NUnit 3.4.

In the meantime, you can use NUnitLite to switch your tests to a self-executing test runner.

I wrote a blog post on the process at [Testing .NET Core using NUnit 3](http://www.alteridem.net/2015/11/04/testing-net-core-using-nunit-3/). A quick summary is;

1. Create a .NET Core Console application for your test project.
2. Reference [NUnit](https://www.nuget.org/packages/NUnit/) and [NUnitLite](https://www.nuget.org/packages/NUnitLite/3.2.0) from your test project. You do not need the runner.
3. Modify `main()` to execute the unit tests.

It should look like this;

```
using NUnitLite;
using System;
using System.Reflection;

namespace MyDnxProject.Test
{
  public class Program
  {
    public int Main(string[] args)
    {
      var writter = new ExtendedTextWrapper(Console.Out);
      new AutoRun(typeof(Program).GetTypeInfo().Assembly).Execute(args, writter, Console.In);
    }
  }
}
```

For more complete information, see [my blog post](http://www.alteridem.net/2015/11/04/testing-net-core-using-nunit-3/).

Comment: Thanks @Rob-Rrouse. I got error says: `Argument 2: cannot convert from 'System.IO.TextWriter' to 'NUnit.Common.ExtendedTextWriter'`  . Checked source code,  method signature is ` public int Execute(string[] args, ExtendedTextWriter writer, TextReader reader)'

Comment: I forgot that we updated the signature for the final release. I've updated the code in my answer and should update my blog post too :)

Comment: Another possible update: `dotnet test` is not supported with the VS2017 style `.csproj` project files. The [recommendation](https://github.com/nunit/dotnet-test-nunit/issues/98#issuecomment-271643437) is to use NUnitLite until then.

Answer (score 3):

I did as [Rob-Prouse suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36578232/run-nunit-tests-in-net-core/36579472#36579472), with minor changes. It finally works now.

```
using System;
using System.Reflection;
using NUnitLite;
using NUnit.Common;

........

public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        var writter = new ExtendedTextWrapper(Console.Out);
         new AutoRun(typeof(Program).GetTypeInfo().Assembly).Execute(args, writter, Console.In);

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Some tweaks to the answer, to make it compile.

```
using System;
using System.Reflection;
using NUnit.Common;
using NUnitLite;

namespace NetMQ.Tests
{
    public static class Program
    {
        private static int Main(string[] args)
        {
            using (var writer = new ExtendedTextWrapper(Console.Out))
            {
                return new AutoRun(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly())
                    .Execute(args, writer, Console.In);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Note that you may also have to convert your project from a class library to a console application.